# Validating Java input is an int and is a certain length

Tags: java, validation, loops, while-loop

First off, I appologize for anything I may have done that is obviously wrong. I'm quite new to Java and I am trying the best I can.

Anyways, I have to write a program to validate that a Canadian Social Insurance Number is real. To start the program, I need to be able to ensure that the user's input is of proper type and format (basically be 9 digits long, no letters, spaces, dashes, etc. Only numbers). I can use basic loops to do the validation process, along with if and else statements, and switch's.

So far I have:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sin;

    System.out.print("Please enter a social insurance number with digits only: ");
    sin = kb.next();


    while (sin.length()!=9){
        System.out.print("Enter a valid social insurance number with digits only: ");
        sin = kb.next();
    }

    for (int i=0; i<sin.length(); i++){
        Character c = sin.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                ???What can I put here???
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking that I have to somehow include the for loop in the while statement to make the validation process properly loop back and ask the user to re-type input in the required format.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *I'm thinking that I have to somehow include the for loop in the while statement*: then why don't you do it?

Comment: I am trying to at the moment, it just is getting very ugly with brackets and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate your validation logic from your application flow and re check as many times as you want :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a social insurance number with digits only: ");
        String sin = kb.next();

        // Ask for the user to enter again if entry is not valid
        while (!isValid(sin)) {
            System.out.print("Enter a valid social insurance number with digits only: ");
            sin = kb.next();
        }

        // Move on
    }

    // Check for validity seperately
    public static boolean isValid(String input)
    {
        // Does it have nine characters
        if(input.length() != 9)
            return false;

        // Is it a number ?
        try
        {
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Passed all checks must be valid
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this would probably be a lot easier if we were taught these types of operators/mehtods/whatnot. I honestly have never worked with catch's and try statements, and have no idea what they do. Is there a way to do this (even if it is the long way to do so), using very basic java methods?

Comment: When an exception is thrown within the try block, it can be caught by a catch statement (when a problem occurs instead of terminating the thread can continue executing). So, the try catch block only checks whether the input is a number or not. Besides this I don't know how simpler it can possibly be =)

Comment: We are only supposed to have one "public static ..." statement within our code. We're only supposed to use the knowledge that we have learned in class, and so far none of that has been covered.

I'm sorry if it seems like I am being difficult, I really do appreciate the help.